# Resetting a well-protected Google account password

Tags: passwords, google

Situation: a new client came to me because of a torrent of identity theft issues. One of the issues: several of their Google accounts were having their passwords changed every few days. Each time, they'd lose access, and someone else would use the accounts for mischief-making.

Three obvious security holes surfaced:

1. Someone had added email routing rules to Outlook on their computers that sent any emails from Google that mentioned accounts, security, passwords, resets, alerts, et al to bit oblivion.
2. They were not using 2-factor validation on the accounts. So, when a password reset was requested by some malefactor, they were not getting a chance to block it with their phones.
3. They'd set up a recovery email address that was @ their own website.com, and access to those email accounts and their settings was shared with and controlled by their website vendor

Given those holes, one could imagine an easy way to change the Google accounts' passwords: start to log in to the account, click "Forgot my password", and get a password reset link sent to the recovery email address @ their own website.com. My client would see none of the relevant emails.

Such an attack would point to their website vendor as a possible perp. Or, sloppy email credentials handling at their hosting service.

So: I added 2-factor validation to the Google accounts, using their phones as validators, and changed the recovery email addresses to a Google account that they controlled, away from their website.com and any possible malfeasance or incompetence at that attack surface.

That stopped the password changing problem cold. No issues for the next 6 weeks.

Then yesterday: the password was changed on one of their Google accounts, now protected from such changes via 2-factor validation and a Google recovery email address under their sole control.

Anyone have any idea how that might have been pulled off? All I can think of is malware on their phones hijacking the 2-factor validation process.

Comment: who has access to the recovery email? if it's one of your client's employees, maybe it's the same employee that had admin level privileges before you took over?

Comment: > who has access to the recovery email

Only the client. None of their employees.

Comment: sounds like this person is extremely vulnerable to phishing attacks.  The attacker could man-in-the-middle the 2fa.  Could also be a malicious browser extension, sim-swap, etc... etc..  best advice to give them is to stop clicking links in emails.

Comment: Browsers clean of malicious extensions.

No sim-swap or sim-dupes.